# how to set textFiledPlaceholder text randomly From array

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have four text field and array of 24- element . how to get four element randomly to set placeholder text.

Comment: show what you tried...unless no one can help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [shuffle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994753-shuffle) on your array and then just pick the first four elements

```
myArray.shuffle()

textfield1.text = myArray[0] // or textfield1.placeholder = myArray[0] 
textfield2.text = myArray[1]
textfield3.text = myArray[2]
textfield4.text = myArray[3]
```

based on your query here we updated the answer

```
placeHolderText.shuffle()
for index in 0...3 {
   textInputLayout(at: index).placeHolderText = "(placeHolderText[index])" 
 }
```

Comment: textInputLayout(at: 0).placeHolderText = "\(placeHolderText.shuffled())" .     i have try this but it print all elements in array

Comment: @vikaspatidar I don't really understand your code but you should only shuffle the array once (and I was referring to your 24 element array in case you have several)

Comment: i just want to change the text field placeholder text every time when viewDidLoad method call

Comment: func textInputLayout(at index:Int) -> TextInputLayout {
        return phraseRecoveryStackView.arrangedSubviews[index] as! TextInputLayout
    } .

Comment: @vikaspatidar then add my code to `viewDidLoad`, I used the `text` property and not the `placeholder` property in my example but that is easy to change

Comment: var placeHolderText =["world2","world3","world4","world5","world2","world3","world4","world5"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            textInputLayout(at: 0).placeHolderText = "\(placeHolderText[0])"
            textInputLayout(at: 1).placeHolderText = "\(placeHolderText[1])"
            textInputLayout(at: 2).placeHolderText = "\(placeHolderText[2])"
            textInputLayout(at: 3).placeHolderText = "\(placeHolderText[3])"
    }

Comment: So in my answer `myArray` corresponds to `placeHolderText` and `textfield1.text` corresponds to `textInputLayout(at: 0).placeHolderText`and so on

Comment: check the updated answer, but its my sugeestion create the common method and update your query